# Regex: Find a string within different string variations

Tags: c#, regex

I need to find a Regex that gets hold of the

> 81.03

part (varies, but always has the structure XX.XX) in following string variations:

> Projects/75100/75120/75124/AR1/75124_AR1_HM2_**81.03**-testing-b405.tgz

> Projects/75100/75130/75138/LM1/75138_LM1_HM2_**81.03**.tgz

I´ve come up with:

```
var regex = new Regex("(.*_)(.*?)-");
```

but this only matches up to the first example string whereas

```
var regex = new Regex("(.*_)(.*?)(.*\.)");
```

only matches the second string.

The path to the file constantly changes as does the "-testing..." postfix.

Any ideas to point me out in the right direction?

Comment: "_I need to find a Regex that gets hold of `81.03`_". That would be `new Regex("81\.03")`, or are your requirements more specific than that?

Comment: `var result = Regex.Match(text, @".*_(\d+\.\d+)")?.Groups[1].Value;`? Is it always after last `_`?

Comment: Yes, the "81.03" also varies as it represents a version number. I forgot to mention that, sorry

Comment: I edited my question now to be more specific

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Wow, it works! Thanks a lot. Post it as an answer if you want

Comment: `\d{2}\.\d{2}`?

Comment: Thanks @JohnathanBarclay for having a go. Wiktors answer works perfectly for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
var result = Regex.Match(text, @".*_(\d+\.\d+)")?.Groups[1].Value;
```

Or, if the string can have more dot+number parts:

```
var result = Regex.Match(text, @".*_(\d+(?:\.\d+)+)")?.Groups[1].Value;
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ezZ6d9/1/).

In general, the regex will extract dot-separated digit chunks after the last `_`.

**Details**

- `.*` - any 0 or more chars other than a newline, as many as possible
- `_` - a `_` char
- `(\d+(?:\.\d+)+)` - Group 1: one or more digits followed with one or more occurrences of a dot followed with one or more digits
- `\d+\.\d+` - one or more digits, `.` and one or more digits.

Answer (score 0):

To match the value `81.03` another option is to match the digits with optional decimal part after the last forward slash after the first underscore.

```
_(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)[^/\r\n]*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oGk9K2/1)

**Explanation**

- `_` Match literally
- `(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` Capture group 1, match 1+ digits with an optional decimal part
- `[^/\r\n]*` Match 0+ chars except `/` or a newline
- `$` End of string